# Website works fine on chrome but not on mozilla or IE

Tags: javascript, css, html, google-chrome

I am developing a pure HTML5 website 
which is working fine on chrome but when i open it in mozilla or IE it's not working . 
even though i have reset my css

```
 html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  font-weight: inherit;
  font-style: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

still mozilla is giving me some padding and margin issue 
here is the css code

```
    .container1 {
    top:100px;
    position: relative;
     width: 1104px;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

and this is header code

```
    .header{
  /*padding: 3em 0;*/
  position: relative;
  width: 95%;
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 100%;
   position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
 background-color:white;
  }
```

this code works fine in chrome but not on mozilla

[image]

[image]

first image is the output from mozilla 
and the second one is from chrome

Comment: The browser DOM inspector should be able to show you where the element layout details are coming from.

Comment: If you put `position: relative` on the body, does it make any difference?

Comment: no it doesn't make any difference

Comment: The screenshots look like two different ad blockers at work. Mozilla's just doesn't show the content, while Chrome's collapses the whole ad. Anyway, you have both `position:relative` and `position:fixed` for the header. Which one of these did you want?

Comment: i want `position:fixed` for the header

Answer (score 0):

Let me be honest with you and tell you to re-look at the way it is coded. Anyways to solve your issue all you need to do is:

```
.container1 {
  /* top: 100px; */
  position: relative;
  width: 1104px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Remove: **top: 100px** will fix it( meaning just the fixed menu being at same spot).

As I said there are better ways to get this looking in shape(like the responsive flow). Good luck.

Comment: but when i remove top:100px; header overlaps the slider.. that's why i put `top:100px;`

Comment: what browser are you seeing this?